# How to remove input default zero value when onChange?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I use `chakra-ui` input

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/input/usage

```
import { Input } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const [shareInputValue, setShareInputValue] = useState(0);

                        <Input
                            type="number"
                            textAlign={'center'}
                            borderRadius={0}
                            border="1px solid #E2E8F0;"
                            value={shareInputValue}
                            onChange={e => {
                                const enterValue = e.target.value;
                                console.log('enterValue', enterValue);
                                const removeZeroStartValue = enterValue.replace(/^0+/, '');
                                console.log('removeZeroStartValue', removeZeroStartValue);
                                setShareInputValue(Number(removeZeroStartValue));
                            }}
                        />
```

When I type 1 the Input will show 01 and continue to type 1 the Input will show 011

I think it should become 1 and 11 ?

![enter image description here

[image]

I try to use `removeZeroStartValue` and then setState, but it's not working

How to fix the issue ?

[image]

Comment: Why manipulate the value in an input field with JS and regex? Simply use the `value= 0` attribute and it will change as soon as you enter something different on its own. No JS or regex required.

Comment: Because when I type 1, the input will show 01

Comment: it must come from another script then but not from the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly setting the value to `0` in your default state. Set it to `null` and add a placeholder instead.

```
const [shareInputValue, setShareInputValue] = useState(null);


  

  <Input
      type="number"
      textAlign={"center"}
      borderRadius={0}
      border="1px solid #E2E8F0;"
      placeholder="0"
      value={shareInputValue}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setShareInputValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
```